# SSL redirection

Tags: https, security-certificate

I want to redirect one of my domain hosted in a domain provider to a different server where I have a Tomcat based application installed. I have purchased SSL for the server with Tomcat installed. The redirect works fine, however in the browser I see the message "server's certificate does not match the url".

Comment: Unless is its a wildcard cert if it was issued for www.you.com its not valid on somethingelse.you.com, whats the cert domain and the tomcat domain?

Comment: Do you mean you use an internal redirect? If so, you need to have your certificate installed in the first receiving server. If you do an external redirect: do you still get the error going to that server directly?

Answer (score 1):

What this warning means is, that the CN of the certificate being presented by the server during SSL handshake does not match the URL the user requested.
To be honest I am not quite sure how you network configuration should change.
As a first comment, you could just ignore this, since you already purchased the certificate.
But if the configuration on the client side is stricter (i.e. to validate the host name, your server would not be accessed as "untrusted").
I suspect that the certificate is issued to an IP and not an FQDN.
If it was issued to an FQDN and your server's IP (you redirect the request to) resolves to that FQDN you would have no such issue.